# How can I prevent Drupal to add extra <p> tags to body field?

Tags: 7, input-formats, nodes

I have a content type with body field. I have created few nodes of this content type. When I edit them, I see that there are extra `<p>` tags have been added to the text of body field. I checked in the `field_data_body` table in databse and found that HTML tags were there as well in the `body_value` column for each entry.

I google for it and found out two probable causes:

1. Using an MCE adds extra HTML tags.
2. If input format used for body field has *'Convert line breaks into HTML'* option enabled.

I checked and found that neither do I use any MCE, nor do I have the *'Convert line breaks into HTML'* option enabled for the input format used.

What else might be causing the addition of extra HTML tags and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Are you using any editors, such as CKeditor, WSYSG..?

Comment: @xurshid29: No..